# Perl multiline regex for first 3 individual items

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I am trying to read a regex format in Perl. Sometimes instead of a single line I also see the format in 3 lines.

For the below single line format I can regex as

```
/^\s*(.*)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9._]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/
```

to get the first 3 individual items in line

```
Hi There       FirstName.LastName    10  3/23/2011 2:46 PM
```

Below is the multi-line format I see. I am trying to use something like

```
/^\s*(.*)\n*\n*|\s+([a-zA-Z0-9._]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/m
```

to get individual items but don’t seem to work.

```
Hi There    

                         FirstName-LastName       8       7/17/2015 1:15 PM 

Testing - 12323232323 Hello There
```

Any suggestions? Is multi-line regex possible?

NOTE: In the same output i can see either Single line or Multi line or both so output can be like below

Hello Line1       FirstName.LastName    10  3/23/2011 2:46 PM

Hello Line2

```
                         Line2FirstName-LastName       8       7/17/2015 1:15 PM 

Testing - 12323232323 Hello There
```

Hello Line3       Line3FirstName.LastName    8 3/21/2011 2:46 PM

Comment: What is the expected output? `FirstName-LastName` won't match `[a-zA-Z0-9._]+`. And what is allowed as "items in a line"?

Comment: I think you need just to add `-` in part `[a-zA-Z0-9._]` like `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]` ;).

Comment: `.*` might be too broad for the first item. Perhaps you should reduce it to `\S+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for sure apply regex over multiple lines.

I've used the negated word `\W+` between words to match space and newlines between words (actually `\W` is equal to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
The chat is viewed as a repetead `\w+\W+` block.

If you provide more specific input / output case i can refine the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $input = <<'__END__';
Hi There    

                         FirstName-LastName       8       7/17/2015 1:15  PM 

Testing - 12323232323 Hello There
__END__

my ($chat,$username,$chars,$timestamp) = $input =~ m/(?im)^\s*((?:\w+\W+)+)(\w+[-,\.]\w+)\W+(\d+)\W+([0-1]?\d\/[0-3]?\d\/[1-2]\d{3}\s+[0-2]?\d:[0-5]?\d\s?[ap]m)/;

$chat =~ s/\s+$//;  #remove trailing spaces

print "chat -> ${chat}\n";
print "username -> ${username}\n";
print "chars -> ${chars}\n";
print "timestamp -> ${timestamp}\n";
```

**Legenda**

- `m/^.../` match regex (not substitute type) starting from start of line
- `(?im)`: case insensitive search and multiline (^/$ match start/end of line also)
- `\s*` match zero or more whitespace chars (matches spaces, tabs, line breaks or form feeds)
- `((?:\w+\W+)+)` (match group $chat) match one or more a pattern composed by a single word `\w+` (letters, numbers, '_') followed by not words `\W+`(everything that is not `\w` including newline `\n`). This is later filtered to remove trailing whitespaces
- `(\w+[-,\.]\w+)`: (match group $username) this is our weak point. If the username is not composed by two regex words separated by a dash `'-'` or a comma `','` (**UPDATE**) or a dot `'.'` the entire regex cannot work properly (i've extracted both the possibilities from your question, is not directly specified).
- `(\d+)`: (match group $chars) a number composed by one or more digits
- `([0-1]?\d\/[0-3]?\d\/[1-2]\d{3}\s+[0-2]?\d:[0-5]?\d\s[ap]m)`: (match group $timestamp) this is longer than the others split it up:

  - `[0-1]?\d\/[0-3]?\d\/[1-2]\d{3}` match a date composed by month (with an optional leading zero), a day (with an optional leading zero) and a year from 1000 to 2999 (a relaxed constraint :)
  - `[0-2]?\d:[0-5]?\d\s?[ap]m` match the time: hour:minutes,optional space and 'pm,PM,am,AM,Am,Pm...' thanks to the case insensitive modifier above

You can test it online [here](http://ideone.com/n01xNq)

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. In  my scenario apart from multiline there could be single line as well like below:


Hi There       FirstName.LastName    10  3/23/2011 2:46 PM


I am trying to get a RegEx which handles if the line output is Single as well as MultiLine.

Please suggest if you have any thoughts.

Comment: @sureng: the regex already works for multiline and singleline input. As i write above the weak point is the ``$username`` part. In the single line input you provided Firstname is separated from Lastname by a dot. I've considered (using your previous examples comma ``','`` and dash ``'-'``. I've updated the answer to consider also the dot ``'.'``

Comment: @sureng: now the [online example](http://ideone.com/n01xNq) apply the regex on both single and multilines input.

Comment: @GsussRecovery Thank you so much. You are correct. i didn't consider the -. It works in both scenarios!....

Comment: Interesting thing is i am getting the above output from another program. Since i am reading line by line multiple RegEx doesn't work. Is there a way to read single line or Multiline based on RegEx format. The 3 formats i gave could be in the same output.

Comment: I posted another question to get single line or multiline.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093262/read-single-line-or-double-line-or-triple-line-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment54002623_33093262

Comment: @sureng: in this answer i've used a *slurp* approach (all input in memory) but i've forgotten to add the multiline regex modifier ``(?m)`` to make ``[^$]`` match start/end of line (instead of only start/end of the input). For processing the input as a stream (because it is a stream or because it's a very large file) you can use the answer i'll give you in the other question. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

### Your regex says:

```
^\s*(.*)\n*\n*  # line starts with optional space followed by anything 
|      # or
\s+([a-zA-Z0-9._]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$ # spaces followed by any words followed by spaces, digits, spaces,  anything at the end of the line
```

### Consider this:

```
/^From|To$/
```

Alternation sticks as close to the sequences. 
Above is really saying to find a line starting with 'Fro' followed by 'm' or 'T', followed by 'o', followed by the end of line

### Compare to this:

```
    /^(From|To)$/
```

Above will find lines that only have 'From' or 'To'